# Set virtual host for redirect to multiple web server (apache)

Tags: apache

Don't know what the perfect title for this, but here it is.

I'm running a server with Windows Server 2008 R2.

On this server I have three webapps and it already run well

1. App1 using Apache2 on port 80
2. App2 using IIS on port 81
3. App3 using Xampp Apache on port 83

I already have a domain for each port
1. domain1.com for port 80
2. domain2.com for port 81
3. domain3.com for port 83

all domain has been pointing to server, and it is work fine when I use (:port) behind the domain, eg. domain1:83 is already open Xampp Apache on port 83.

however, what I need is when I type domain1.com it should open port 80, domain2.com it should open port 81, and domain3.com should open port 83.

Simple say, I don't need to add :81 or :83 if I want to open those sites.

Main apache server used are Apache2, and I need configuration to automatically when I type domain2.com it goes to port 81 (localhost:81), and so if I type domain3.com it goes to port 83 (localhost:83)

Meaning is, that Apache2 only handle App1 on port 80, when I want to access App2 using domain2.com then it refer to localhost:81 then the process will be handled by IIS, and so for App3 using domain3.com it refer to localhost:83 then Xampp will handle the process.

Every Apps has different config so I cannot put it to single port 80 then difference it by DocumentRoot since other Apps are not processed by Apache2.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Set up a [name-based virtual host support](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html) on Apache. It is handling port 80, so it will handle all requests to port 80, no matter what port number is used.

You then have two options.

- Redirect
- Proxy

You can redirect the traffic to the other port (which will show the port number in the address bar of the browser, and cause search engines to index URLs with that port number in them)

```
Redirect / http://domain2.com:81/
```

Or you can [proxy the traffic through Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html) (which will relay everything through Apache, which could have performance implications):

```
ProxyPass "/"  "http://domain2.com:81/"
```

Comment: sorry for late reply, failed to know that someone has submit an answer.

So,

Comment: So, I already tried above method and nothing works, that's why I submit this question.

as for using above method, 
Redirect / http://domain2.com:81/ 
leads to typing domain1.com/ also referring to port:81, 
what I need is if type domain1.com it goes to port 81, if type domain2.com it goes to port 83
with Redirect, we should use / meaning if I want to access port 81 then I must set domain1.com/domain1

Comment: @estobayus — If typing domain1.com gets a redirect to domain2.com:81 then you missed the the first paragraph of the answer.